# How can I export to PDF in JasperReports 6.1: alternate of using JRPdfExporter.setParameter method

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

How i can export to PDF in JasperReports 6.1?

I used this code with *JasperReports API 5.2*:

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(getServletContext().getRealPath(url), parametros, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(listadoDatos));
JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, out);
exporter.exportReport();
```

But the code below is not working for *JR API 6.1*:

```
  JasperPrint jasperPrint;  
  if (conConexion) {
      jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(getServletContext().getRealPath(url), parametros, conexion);
      conexion.close(); 
  } else {
      jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(getServletContext().getRealPath(url), parametros, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(listaDatos));
  }
  JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
  exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
  exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(nombreReporte+".pdf"));
  SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
  exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
  exporter.exportReport();
```

How I can rewrite this code?

Comment: I posted your solution as *community wiki answer*. You can post the same (in this case I'll delete this answer) or you can accept this one

Answer (score 8):

The answer by @LuisNeira

This is solution:

```
JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(outputStream));
SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
configuration.setPermissions(PdfWriter.AllowCopy | PdfWriter.AllowPrinting);
exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
exporter.exportReport();
```